# Why is firestore where clause not working with state?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-cloud-firestore, where-clause

I am trying to filter documents from firestore using where clause in react js. However when i use a state variable in the where clause it is not working but when i provide an actual string it starts working

Not working

```
firebase.firestore().collection('Partners')
    .where("Email",'==',this.state.currentUser).get().then( querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {

        this.setState({
          Theatre:doc.data().Theatre
        })

    })
})
```

working

```
firebase.firestore().collection('Partners')
    .where("Email",'==',"test@test.com").get().then( querySnapshot => {
      querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {

        this.setState({
          Theatre:doc.data().Theatre
        })

    })
})
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

**EDIT**
I even tried `console.log(this.state.currentUser==='test@test.com')` and it is coming true. Yet the where clause is not working with the state variable

Comment: You're going to have to do some debugging and figure out what the value of `this.state.currentUser` is at the time you use it.  `console.log()` should help.

Comment: What is in state.currentUser is it an email if not that would be the error

Answer (score 0):

Might be the problem with your state variable, like async effects of `setState` or any other possible reasons.

Make sure your state variable `currentUser` has a value. For that safety, run this function in an `if` condition:

```
if(this.state.currentUser){
 firebase.firestore().collection('Partners')
     .where("Email",'==',this.state.currentUser).get().then( querySnapshot => {
       querySnapshot.forEach(doc => {

         this.setState({
           Theatre:doc.data().Theatre
         })

     })
 })
}
```

For debugging, try console logging it.

Comment: I did console log the state inside querysnapshot and the value is fine. But the control is not entering the foreach loop.

Comment: Might be possible that it doesn't find the particular document having Email set as your state variable value?

Comment: But when i hard code the email string in the where clause it works fine, and the state variable has the same value.

Answer (score 0):

React state is asynchronous you do get a state value in a console but by the time firestore query is ran because it is also asynchronous your state is somehow getting override or maybe your the page is getting refreshed and state is being set again.

I had this same issue and then I checked my page was getting refreshed and I was losing the state I set even though I did got it inside the console.log() but by the time my firestore where query ran there was not state.

You need to provide the whole code here in order for us to take a look at it.