# How in Firestore show only documents that belong to a specific uid?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

What I'm trying to achieve is to only show the **documents** that match `request.auth.uid`. I've seen these examples on a lot of website but none of them seems to work for me. No matter what article I read I see these examples there but none of them seems to work for me. I have a (posts) collection with bunch of documents with auto-generated (ids).

[image]
[image]

```
// I cannot attach more than 2 images it gives me formatting error that's why.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/M84P5.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hbBii.png
https://i.stack.imgur.com/lm4HH.png


rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /posts/{postId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId;    // This doesn't work
    }
  }
}


rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /posts/{postId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == postId;    // This also doesn't work
    }
  }
}

rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /posts/{postId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid != null;     // even though this works fine but it is general.
    }
  }
}
```

Below I've shared my code.

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { social: [], loggedIn: "false" };
  }

  componentDidMount = () => {
    firestore.collection("posts").onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
      const social = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => {
        return { id: doc.id, ...doc.data() };
      });
      this.setState({
        social
      });
    });
  };

//   clickHandle(id, likes) {
//     firestore
//       .collection("posts")
//       .doc(id)
//       .update({ likes: likes + 1 });
//   }

  handleCreate() {
    var obj = { title: "Never Ever GIve Up" };
    firestore.collection("posts").add(obj);
  }

  handleDelete(id) {
    firestore.collection("posts").doc(id).delete();
  }

  handleLogin() {
    var provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    auth.signInWithPopup(provider).then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
  }

  handleLogout() {
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged((user) => {
      auth.signOut();
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.handleLogin.bind(this)}>Login to Google</button>
        <button onClick={this.handleLogout.bind(this)}> Logout from Google</button>
        {this.state.social.map((obj) => {
          return (
            <h1>{obj.title} </h1>
          );
        })}
        <br />
        <button id="create" onClick={this.handleCreate.bind(this)}>
          Create
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.querySelector("#root"));
```

Comment: Security rules don't have much meaning without also seeing the specific queries that they are intended to allow or reject.  Please edit the question to show the queries that are not working the way you expect.

Comment: @DougStevenson just added the image.

Comment: No, I'm asking for the client code that performs the query. A screenshot of more rules is not helpful here.

Comment: @DougStevenson just added more images that show code as well.

Comment: On Stack Overflow, don't share images of code.  Copy the code into the question itself so that it's easy to read, copy, and search.

Comment: @DougStevenson sure, next time 'll keep that in mind. Btw, I've shared my code in text as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that [Firestore security rules are not filters](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/security/rules-query#rules_are_not_filters).  Please read that documentation carefully, and also [this blog](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/what-does-it-mean-that-firestore-security-rules-are-not-filters-68ec14f3d003).

Your query is asking for all documents in the posts collection.  However, your rules do not allow that.  The rules will not filter the documents that match the rules.  Instead, your client app needs to filter for the documents that the user should be able to read, and your rules need to validate that filter.

If you want to require the userId field to be the same as the authenticated user ID for the purpose of reading the document, your query needs to add a filter to ensure they aren't asking for anything more than they have permission to read:

```
firestore.collection("posts").where("userId", "==", uid)
```

Where `uid` is the user ID that you got from the Firebase Auth SDK.

Then your rules can check to see that the filter is correct:

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /posts/{postId} {
      allow read: if request.auth.uid == resource.data.userId;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I just figured this out myself as well but now I've ran into another problem and that is if I pass (uid) as variable after storing state inside it like (var uid = this.state.email) then it doesn't work but if I pass it manually in a string like "123" then it works. Don't know why, I'm trying to figure it out for like past 1hr but nothing seems to work. Thanks for help though.

Comment: I found someone else having similar issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61807388/why-is-firestore-where-clause-not-working-with-state

Comment: Again, if you have a new question, please post it separately, and explain fully what you're doing in the code that doesn't work the way you expect.

Answer (score 0):

I bet you're doing something funky with your requests.

`resource.data` will return the attributes of the document accessed. In your first example, this will work if the document at path `posts/{post_id}` has the attribute `userId`, and the `userId` attribute matches the `uid` of the incoming request context. I would verify the structure of each document in the posts collection to check that it matches.

The first example should work, I would double-check the user id matches of the sender. Check the "Authentication" tab of your Firebase console. (In the document shown, looks like the `userId` is the id of another post, which might indicate some misbehavior?)

The second example won't work because the document doesn't have a `postId` attribute.

Comment: Nothing works and I've also shared the image of my database and documents, attributes inside them. I don't know why it doesn't work because I've read bunch of articles sharing these examples but for me somehow it doesn't work.

Comment: Please print your firebase.auth.uid before making the request and add an image of the print and request.